# how do i print a string with a variable that contains a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and I want to print the **average** variable as a float after the string but I keep getting an error. How can I fix this. Edit: I've added the start of my code in case it helps

```
numbers = input ("Enter a list of numbers with a comma \",\" in between ")
total_num = 0
for num in numbers:
    total_num += 1
    
average = float(sum(numbers)/total_num)
print ("The average is " , average)
```

This is the error I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

When I try this with python 2.6 it worked perfectly but I'm using python 3.7.1 and it has stopped working

Comment: There's no `+` in your code, you can't have gotten that error.

Comment: What happens if you do `sum(numbers)` by itself? Looks most likely that `numbers` is a list that contains a string, and so it's `sum()` that's complaining it can't add a string to an int.

Comment: That error would happen if you wrote `print ("The average is " + average)`

Comment: @Barmar, no, that exception is raised, for example, by `sum([1, "2"])`.

Comment: @Barmar that would be `str + float`, perhaps the error ir from another line

Comment: The OP needs to post the value of `numbers` and the full traceback.

Comment: @Barmar i've added  the start of my code, could there be a problem there?

Comment: In Python 2.x, `input()` evaluates the input, in Python 3 it just returns a string. You need ti split the input and convert each element to `float`.

Comment: There's no need to use a `for` loop to count the elements in a list. Just use `total_num = len(numbers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the `sum(numbers)`. `input()` function returns a string, and sum() function tries to iterates and sum the characters of the string...
(It worked in python 2 as Python 2's input() function evaluates the string, and in this case returned a list of numbers ...)

You need to separate the numbers (using `split(',')`) and convert the list of strings to float.

This will work:

```
numbers = input ("Enter a list of numbers with a comma \",\" in between ")
numbers = [float(x) for x in numbers.split(',')]

total_num = 0
for num in numbers:
    total_num += 1

average = float(sum(numbers)/total_num)
print ("The average is " , average)
```

(The code can be improved in many ways, I focused on the problem described ...)

Comment: Will +1 if you explain why it works in python2 but not python3 (difference between `input` methods)

Answer (score 2):

### Edit 2:

Python2's `input` was an unsafe method as it applied `eval` on your input value.
Python3's `input` uses what was known in Python2 as `raw_input`.

Therefore, in order to parse your numbers the way you receive them now:

```
numbers = input ("Enter a list of numbers with a comma \",\" in between ")
numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers.split(',')]
```

or even better, to work with input that has whitespaces and commas and just easily ignore them:

```
import re

numbers = input ("Enter a list of numbers with a comma \",\" in between ")
numbers = [int(n) for n in re.findall("\d+", numbers)]
```

---

### <s>Edit:</s>

Seems like the origin of your problem has to do something with your `numbers` list.
 If it's a list of numbers represented in strings, you will have to cast them to ints (or floats) first:

```
sum(int(n) for n in numbers)
sum(float(n) for n in numbers)
```

so it will be:

```
average = sum(float(n) for n in numbers)/len(numbers) # Python3 division result by default are float
```


---

Other printing ways:
You can simply use f-string on Python3.6+:

```
average = float(sum(numbers)/total_num)
print(f"The average is {average}")
```

On older Python versions, you can either:

```
print("The average is {}".format(average))
print("The average is %f" % average) # Float formatted
print("The average is %d" % average) # Int formatted
print("The average is " + str(average))
```

And finally, your print should have worked as well:

```
print("The average is", str(average))
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be coming from printing the result.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `input()` magically applied the built-in `eval()` function to the string the user enters.

But that was thought to be a "security risk", so in Python 3 `input()` returns the string the user entered, unevaluated.

So, e.g., if the user typed

1, 2, 3

under Python 2, `input()` returned the *tuple* `(1, 2, 3)`. but under Python 3 it returns the *string* `"1, 2, 3"`. Under Python 3, you'll have to apply `eval()` to that string yourself (understanding that it's "a security risk", since `eval()` can end up doing anything at all, depending on what the user typed).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `numbers` is a single string.

You need to split the string and then cast the entries to an int. That will give you this for the first two lines:

```
numbers = input("Enter a list of numbers with a comma \",\" in between ").split(',')
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
```

You can then just delete the entire for loop and instead just use `len(numbers)`

***Final Code***

```
numbers = input("Enter a list of numbers with a comma \",\" in between ").split(',')
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
total_num = 0

average = float(sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
print("\n The average is ", average)
```